# Bootstrap dynamically displaying flex items and cannot start a new row

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I'm implementing code where I dynamically display flex items where each one takes 1/2 the display width, so after two items I need to start a new row.
**class="d-flex flex-row"** doesn't seem to do that for me. How can I essentially as a 
 after every two items displayed?

```
    <div class="d-flex mb-3">
        <div class="card col-6 m-3">
            <p>Card 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 m-3">
            <p>Card 2</p>                
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row"></div>
        <div class="card col-6 m-3">
            <p>Card 3</p>                
        </div>
        <div class="card col-6 m-3">
            <p>Card 4</p>                
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are very close! I think the issue is flex calculating margins in the width of the element, so you effectively have a (50% + margin) element specified in your `col-6 m-3` classes. This pushes the elements to the next row.

The solution is to apply a wrapper containing the layout class `col-6` and leave the margin on the children.

You also do not have a `row` class on the parent of your columns, so be sure to add that as well!

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row d-flex flex-row mb-3">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card m-3">
            <p>Card 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card m-3">
            <p>Card 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card m-3">
            <p>Card 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card m-3">
            <p>Card 4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's is strictly the row & col class that work. Flex doesn't seem to help for this scenario.

Comment: That's true, you probably want one or the other here. You could use `flex-basis` and/or `width` to specify 50% width flex children instead of `col-6` if you wanted to move away from Bootstrap in your project. Otherwise, if it isn't broken....

Answer (score 1):

use `row` to make  row instead of `d-flex flex-row` your code should be like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="card col-6">
        <p>Card 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-6">
        <p>Card 2</p>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="card col-6">
        <p>Card 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card col-6">
        <p>Card 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

(card 3 and 4 will automatically go to a new row as there's no remaining space for them)
I removed the margin as if you added margins the card space will be more than 50%
if you want to add space around the card you can make the cards inside divs and give the divs `col-6` and then give the divs `p-3` like that:

```
<div class="row w-100 mx-auto">
    <div class="col-6 p-3">
        <div class="card">
            <p>Card 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 p-3">
        <div class="card">
            <p>Card 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="col-6 p-3">
        <div class="card">
            <p>Card 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 p-3">
        <div class="card">
            <p>Card 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```